# Geometric characteristics of a Transformation that squares the components of a vector

Tags: vector-analysis, transformation

Is there any interesting geometric (or any of kind) characteristic of a transformation T of a vector X in $R^n$ so that the components get squared? 
i.e. $T(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1^2, x_2^2,..., x_n^2)$
for any $X= (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ in $R^n$.

I'm especially looking for a geometric relation between the vectors before and after the transformation.

Comment: Interesting question! It's not quite what you're asking, but a place to start is that the direction of the vector will move toward the axis corresponding to the largest component, and the magnitude will move away from 1